# ActivityTranstition between two ViewPager's which both contains adapters

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-animation, material-design

I'm in some desperat need for help, so hold on to your hats, because here we go:

I have two activity's I need to transition between. Each activity contains a ViewPager and each ViewPager has a PagerAdapter who's responsible for creating fragment's I can swip between.

In Activity **A** I have a fragment which contains one large imageView
In Activity **B** I have a fragment which containt a RecyclerGridView, which contains a grid of ImageView's.

So the transition I wanna archive: 
Activity **A** -> PagerAdapter -> Fragment -> *ImageView* 
Activity **b** -> PagerAdapter -> Fragment -> RecyclerView -> *ImageView*

I know I have to use the `postponeEnterTransition();` and `startPostponedEnterTransition();` but I can't figure out when to call the `startPostponedEnterTransition();` to get the timing right.

Activity **A** where I start Activity **B**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, PagesOverviewActivity.class);
if (Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
   final PageRecyclingImageView pageRecyclingImageView = ((PageDetailFragment) mAdapter.getFragment(mPager.getCurrentItem())).getPageRecyclingImageView();
   ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(PageActivity.this, pageRecyclingImageView, "page_number_" + getCurrentPageNumber());
   startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
}
```

OnCreate in Activity **B** I call postponeTransition and create my PagerAdapter called *PagesOverviewFragmentAdapter*

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    postponeEnterTransition();
    ...
    mFragmentAdapter = new PagesOverviewFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), sections, getApplicationContext());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mFragmentAdapter);
```

In my `PagesOverviewFragmentAdapter.getItem()` I create the Fragment's which contains the RecyclerView

```
public class PagesOverviewFragmentAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    PagesOverviewFragment fragment = PagesOverviewFragment.newInstance();

    return fragment;
}
```

In the **PagesOverviewFragment** I create the adapter, **PagesOverviewAdapter** for my RecyclerView

```
public class PagesOverviewFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pages_overview_fragment_layout, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.pages_overview_recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
    mAdapter = new PagesOverviewAdapter(mSection, getActivity());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter); 
    return view;
```

Finally inside **PagesOverviewAdapter** I create the ImageView which I wanna make the transition to and call `startPostponedEnterTransition` when I hit the imageView which I wanna animate to.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PagesOverviewViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int leftPagePosition;    
    leftPagePosition = mSection.getFirstPage();
    if (Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP <= Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
        holder.mLeftCardView.setTransitionName("page_number_" + leftPagePosition);
    }

    Glide.with(mContext).load(getLocalPathToFile(leftPagePosition)).placeholder(R.drawable.card_cover_placeholder).into(holder.mLeftCardView);
    holder.mLeftCardView.setText(mContext.getString(R.string.page, leftPagePosition));
    if (leftPagePosition == 4) { //Hardcode position 4 for test.
        holder.mLeftCardView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                mActivity.startPostponedEnterTransition();
                holder.mLeftCardView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                return false;
            }
        });
   }
}
```

Wall of text should be done now!
Here is a video of what it looks like in my app: 
http://www.youtubeslow.com/watch?v=crdRjDTy43o 
As you can see the transition work's when I press the back button, so both imageView have the correct transition name, but when I start Activity **B** the imageView goes to the wrong position in my RecyclerView.

If anyone have a idea how to solve this, I'll find you and hug you!